# Querying the mapped value of provider(interface java.util.Set) before task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' has completed is not supported

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

https://github.com/MrAryan8728/Ecommerce

This is my github repo link.I am getting the error in the app.
Plz anyone help me in solving it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In android/build.gradle, update the google-services classpath to 4.3.14:

```
dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
    }
```